# Rails form with remote action for only one field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unobtrusive-javascript

I have a form in Rails 3 that must be submitted with a **normal post**, like this

```
<%= form_for @seller, :as => :seller_user, :url => save_seller_url do |f| %>
```

but one of the field inside needs to execute a remote ajax call to update some value, like this one

```
<%= f.select( ... ) %> => on change please make a remote call to fill new data here
```

I did not found any documentation online to add the **:remote => true** option to the select helper, am I missing something?
what is the correct way of handling this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I wrestled with this for a while too. I think the best "rails way" to do it is like:

```
<%= form_tag(controller: "sellers", action: "your_controller_action") do %>
    OTHER FORM STUFF HERE
    <select name="some_select" id="some_select" onchange="your_javascript_function">
        <option> ... </option>
    </select>
    OTHER FORM STUFF HERE
    <%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
<% end %>
```

Then in your controller to handle the submit, you can refer to this field like normal, as `params[:some_select]`

This assumes your controller is called sellers_controller. More about form_tag [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag) and form_tag helpers [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html)

Comment: therefore you are suggesting not to use the select helper function and to handle the ajax call manually in the javascript handler linked to the onchange event?

Comment: yes. only because i feel like the ease outweighs the hassle of trying to do it with form_for